# Only one of multiple threads is writing

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have a task to make a StarCraft like program with multiple pthreads as workers.

So , I have multiple pthreads that run the following function:

```
void* scv(int num){
    int minerals_carried = 0;
    while(map_minerals_remaining>0){
        minerals_carried = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<number_of_fields; i++){
            if(fields[i].minerals != 0 && minerals_carried == 0){
                if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&fields[i].mutex)==0){
                
                    sleep(1);
                    // mine returns int
                    minerals_carried = mine(&fields[i]);
                    printf("SCV%d is carrying %d minerals from field %d\n",num,minerals_carried,i);
                    
                    if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&fields[i].mutex)!=0){
                        perror("pthread_mutex_unlock");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                }else{
                    perror("pthread_mutex_trylock");
                    return NULL;
                
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I create 5 pthreads and they all get created properly , but only the first one prints out like its supposed to do, and all the other ones dont seem to do anything. Any idea why that might be ?

EDIT :
I was asked to show how I initialized number_of_fields and fields and this is it:
I first declare them as global

```
typedef struct Mineral_Field_t{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    int minerals;

}Mineral_Field;

Mineral_Field* fields;
int number_of_fields = 2;
```

And then I have the following piece of code at the start of the main function:

```
if(argv[1] != NULL){
        number_of_fields = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    fields = malloc(number_of_fields*sizeof(Mineral_Field));
```

Comment: Can you show how you initialize number_of_fields and fields? You declared them as global

Comment: Edited, you should now be able to see what I do.

Comment: Are you sure all the threads are running? The threads that can't get the lock should be reporting an error from `pthread_mutex_trylock` since you're not blocking.

Comment: Oh my, thank you, I am still learning this stuff and I forgot that if the mutex is locked it still returns an error value. I removed the return NULL; part and now everything works as intended.

Comment: You can answer your own question (if Barmar pass) instead of editing the title, it is not that dumb. I upvoted for the nice tribute to starcraft also ;)

Comment: A bit more directly: it is not our custom here to modify titles to indicate that a question has been answered, and I have rolled back that edit.  You may (but are not obligated to) write an answer yourself.  If you wish, you may also accept a self-answer, though that will not gain you any rep.